# How can I better utilize GPUs during CUDA rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm using Cycles with CUDA rendering on a GTX 1070. CPU and GPU utilization during rendering is extremely spiky, most of the time both appear to be doing little work. Is it possible to smooth this out so that utilization is close to 100% all of the time? It seems like my renders could be ~5x faster if the GPU was actually working to its full potential.

[image: screenshot of windows task manager during rendering showing spiky CPU and GPU usage]

Are there knobs I can tweak to try and improve this, or is this expected?

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like you're rendering multiple frames of an animation and you're seeing the scene geometry and bvh build phase on the CPU (unavoidable in many cases) and then the raycasting portion happening on the Cuda cores.

You may be able to take advantage of the cache options for the features you're using, but you'll need to provide a little more detail for a proper response.

Comment: This is likely the explanation, seeing as the CPU graph is spiking when CUDA is at 0 and conversely. Maybe there is a way to render on two Blender instances to take advantage of it ? I think it's highly unlikely to improve render times :)

Comment: @Gorgious I wonder if scheduling would be an even greater issue but it's an interesting idea.